# Are there any best practices and/or tools for cleaning old Docker images on a regular basis?

Tags: docker, toolchain

Is there an elegant way or a best practice when it comes to deleting old images from the Docker registry?

I see a lot of requests/issues here: https://github.com/docker/docker-registry/labels/delete, but didn't find a good/popular solution for it.

**So, is there a tool or a technique which would help me do that?**

Also, is there any best practices which you follow while doing it?

Comment: Are you asking how to clean the registry? (Which is the link and question you provide), but the accepted answer is not cleaning the registry, but cleaning your local docker.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've had good luck with
[Spotify/docker-gc](https://github.com/spotify/docker-gc). It can be run from cron or as a docker container.

> A simple Docker container and image garbage collection script.
>
> - Containers that exited more than an hour ago are removed.
> - Images that don't belong to any remaining container after that are removed.

Comment: At first glance, it seems to be, behind all the bash stuff, more or less a subset of the one-liners from @rombob 's answer. Is that true, or is there some "intelligence" in `docker-gc` that I am missing?

Comment: Op links and asks a question on how to clean from the registry, but docker-gc doesn't clean from the registry, it just cleans from your local machine. I guess OP was really asking how to clean up locally

Comment: Docker-gc's page now recommends to use `docker system prune` instead. But I didn't find how to exclude some images from removing with Docker's prune. It there a way to exclude some images with `docker system prune`?

Answer (score 9):

Can't call it's the best practice but this is what we use triggered by cron, happy to see better suggestions.

```
echo "safely removing untagged images"
docker rmi $(docker images | awk '/<none>/{print $3}')

echo "safely removing stopped containers"
docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)

echo "safely removing old containers"
docker ps -a | awk '/weeks ago|months ago|days ago/{print $1}' | xargs --no-run-if-empty docker rm

echo "safely removing old images"
docker images | awk '/weeks ago|months ago|days ago/{print $3}' | xargs --no-run-if-empty docker rmi

echo "safely removing old volumes, custom rebuild of martin/docker-cleanup-volumes image"
docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v $(readlink -f /var/lib/docker):/var/lib/docker --rm example/docker-cleanup-volumes

echo "native cleanup Docker => 12"
docker system prune -f
```

Comment: Please don't chain grep and awk, do the same filter just before the awk command ` regex { command }`

Comment: @Tensibai anything to make AWK wizards happy :)

Comment: Just in case, that's not just pedantic , you save process spawn and a large bunch of context changes :) It doesn't change much here, but any occasion to advocate for it is good :)

Comment: @Tensibai definitely, good habits pay off with time, spawns cost us time and money :)

Comment: Specially when you parse/format billions lines log files to prepare for R input :) Here I don't expect more than a few dozen lines.

Comment: @Tensibai yep, all these cool new technologies for big data out there, and yet good old awk is still relevant :)

Comment: Variation for first command:  `for i in $(docker images --filter dangling=true -q); do docker rmi "$i"; done` unsure it can replace the `docker images | awk` part.

Answer (score 4):

On my local machine (mac) I have a little script I found that I run periodically which cleans all the excess images up [clean-docker-for-mac.sh](https://gist.github.com/MrTrustor/e690ba75cefe844086f5e7da909b35ce)

For my servers I run [meltwater/docker-cleanup](https://hub.docker.com/r/meltwater/docker-cleanup/) which periodically cleans up exited containers and removes images and volumes that aren't in use.

I use a lot of different Docker images for my work on Codemason that scripts like these are necessity for me. Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

`docker system prune --volumes`

Is the way to do this since v17. [Docs here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/system_prune/)